# Why does Jquery only select the first element with some methods and all elements with other ones?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-video

I'm trying to pause three videos via jQuery.  For some reason, my code only selects the first item when using the .get() method but when I use the .css() method, all relevant elements are selected.  Can somebody help me understand why?

Here's the html:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="item action"><video src="video1.MOV"></video></div>
  <div class="item"><video src="video2.MOV"></video></div>
  <div class="item"><video src="video3.MOV"></video></div>
</div>
```

Here's the jquery using the .get() method that only impacts the first video ("video1.MOV"):

```
$('div.carousel-inner .item').children("video").get(0).pause();
```

Using the .css() method, I was able to select elements with class="item":

```
$('div.carousel-inner .item').children("video").css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Can somebody help me understand why only the first video is being paused?  I'd like to modify the jQuery to pause ALL videos.  Thanks!

Comment: `.get(0)` return the first element as a plain DOM element, while `.get(4)` returns the fifth element, and `get()` returns all elements etc, did you read the documentation? Some jQuery methods will only work on the first element in the collection as it doesn't make sense to iterate internally for those methods.

Comment: adeneo - I understand the .get() method but didn't realize that some jQuery methods only work on the first element in a collection.  Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Adeno confirmed, some jQuery methods only work on the first element in a collection which is why I was only able to pause the first video but not subsequent ones while the .css() method worked on all video elements.

To get all videos to pause, use the following code:

```
$('div.carousel-inner video').each(function(){
  this.pause();
});
```

The way the html is set up, I needed to get the child node of each .item element.

Some information on this:
jQuery has a simple logic, wether a method is called on all or only on the first element. If a method returns something (does not return undefined) jQuery won't iterate through all elements. In this case jQuery will call the method on first element and return the return value of the method. If it returns nothing jQuery will call the method on all elements and returns the jQuery object for chaining.

In this particular case you are using the pause method, which is not a jQuery method but a normal DOM method and has to be called on each DOM element itself. The .get method of jQuery always returns of DOM element inside of the jQuery collection. $.get(0) is used here to return the first DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use,

```
$('div.carousel-inner .item').children("video")
```

to select all those child elements under the class `.item`. `.get(index)` will eventually get the element at the specified index from that collection. So that your are seeing that behaviour.

`$('div.carousel-inner .item').children("video").get(0)`

is very much equals to

`$('div.carousel-inner .item').children("video")[0]`

Please read here to know more about [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: .get() gets all elements from the collection unless an argument containing a valid index is given.

Comment: @KevinB I was in the middle of updating.

Comment: Even with your update the wording is still wrong. i'm not the dv. It doesn't eventually get the first element, it gets the element specified by the index.

Comment: @KevinB As a learner I would like to ask you what's exactly wrong in my post.? Thank you.

Comment: I think it's just a translation issue. Your latest edit just fixed it. Mentioning that it selects the first one is wrong unless you specifically use `0` as the index because .get can be used to select the first one, the third one, or even all of them based on what is passed as the index.

Comment: @KevinB I am learning Jquery as well as English. :D Really Thanks for your time.